# Programmatically highlight ListView element in Universal Windows 10

Tags: c#, listview, win-universal-app

I am trying to implement my own logic in selecting list elements behavior. I want to highlight one option programmatically by position. I found one working solution:

`myListView.SelectedIndex = position;`

This method is "doing a virtual click" on that list item, I just need to programmatically evidentiate the list item but not click it.

My listView implementation in xaml:

```
<ListView
    x:Name="myListView"
    SelectionChanged="onmyListViewItemClick"
    SelectionMode="Single">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <--here I have 2 textBoxes and one image-->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: You want to highlight selecteditem? myListView.SelectedIndex = position-> this selectes particular item

Comment: You can change the visual state to selected for the particular ListView item which you want to highlight.

Comment: I mentioned this method but it trigger `onListItemClick` when I use it, I need just to change visual state with no implicit selection

Comment: @VasileDoe Why do you want to explicitly avoid selection? In the eyes of an ordinary user, highlight means selection.

Comment: It will trigger selectionchanged event because you changed the selection. It's not click event

Comment: but how can I change highlighted element without calling `SelectionChanged="onmyListViewItemClick"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for clearing up the things:

> **ItemClick** Occurs when an item in the list view receives an interaction, and the IsItemClickEnabled property is true. (Inherited from ListViewBase)
>
> **SelectionChanged** Occurs when the currently selected item changes. (Inherited from Selector)

So in your case you should use `ItemClick="onmyListViewItemClick"` in xaml and keep using  `myListView.SelectedIndex = position;` four your needs

So, your xaml ListView shuold be:

```
<ListView
x:Name="myListView"
IsItemClickEnabled="true"
ItemClick="onmyListViewItemClick"
SelectionMode="Single">

<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <--here I have 2 textBoxes and one image-->
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

and for getting trigged element in `onmyListViewItemClick` :

```
 private void onmyListViewItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e) {
        var selectedOption = (YourObjectElement)e.ClickedItem;
        //use your cliked obj data
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

To change highlighted element without firing `SelectionChanged` event, you must implement your own visual state for the ListViewItem and the `IsSelected` property and `SelectedIndex` must not be changed.

To implement the selection states, first create a `UserControl` to use inside the `DataTemplate`. Create a new property bool IsSelected for your model, In the user control you will declare the `VisualState`s of your cell, and it will change the state by using `VisualStateManager` whenever the IsSelected property of the DataContext (your model) of the user control changed.